# Why my python code throws OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I've searched the answers but I can't find any one which can help me.
I don't know why stream is closed when readlines.
This is an occasional problem, and it does not necessarily happen

could you please help me to find some ideas.

the error line is 5

my code is follows:

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 2. 2. stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
process_id = process.pid
(child_stdin, stream) = (process.stdin, process.stdout)
result_bytes = stream.readlines()
```

the command is:

```
sudo -u xxxuser /bin/bash -c "cp -r -p somefile anotherfiledest"
```

Comment: Please post your code without manual line numbering.

Comment: I fixed it.I posted partly code, because the code is in company so I can't post all,sorry

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.